# Disable Moneta logs that log headers and request

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to disable Moneta log headers and request only for Prod but active in the Dev.
requirement in the application-default.yml is like below.

**Dev:**

logging :
http:
logRequestHeaders: true
logRequestEntity: true
logResponseEntity: true

**Prod**

logging :
http:
logRequestHeaders: false
logRequestEntity: false
logResponseEntity: false

Please advice.

I did not try anything .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I tried #moneta.logging.exclude-url-patterns =".*/localhost*"  .
But still all the headers are logging .Is there any other way to achieve it?